# Should a hot network question that you're currently reading appear on the list of them?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

[image: example found in the wild]

This question is a hot question. As a result, there's a link to it in the "hot questions" sidebar. This...is a bit silly. Why is a question linking to itself? I think it would make more sense to remove self-links and instead list whatever hot question is just below the cutoff.