# Why do we see our own questions on the HNQ sidebar?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hot-questions

Many times, I see my own hot network question in the sidebar. Specifically, it is happening frequently with [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/88364/why-was-nine-pin-bowling-illegal-in-most-states-unlike-ten-pin-bowling) on Law. However, it is just a distraction because

1. I already know about it!
2. I get updates on it whenever something happens.
3. It just removes one question from the visible portion of the sidebar, thereby defeating the purpose of HNQs.

Why is it designed to be this way?

Comment: I know I'm Hot but I still like to hear that the Network knows it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's simply not feasible (performance-wise) to make a 'personal' HNQ list. For the same reason, it's possible to see a question in the Hot Network Questions [*on the Q&A page itself*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231452/295232).

Fortunately, there are many other hot questions you can click on, and if you wait [up to three days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/295232), the problem will disappear by itself.

Lastly, as you don't get a notification for your question being selected as Hot Network Question, for me it's a pleasant surprise seeing it there. Though that can often be inferred from the reputation changes ...

Comment: Also, on network sites that are super busy, the number of users possibly affected by this is infinitely small. And on sites that aren't super busy, I just don't see it as all that much of a distraction. As you suggest, even if I notice the reputation, if my question was filtered from the HNQ, how do I possibly know for sure that's why?